# java multiple form count

Tags: java, forms

Hi i have class with form, witch is adding to panel depending on how much machines are in location

```
panel.add(t.initComponents());
for(int i=0; i< machines.size(); i++)
{   
    Form f = new Form();        
    panel.add(f.initComponents());
}
panel.add(new Formsum());
```

1. In each form (new Form) im inputing
   some values which i want to sum (on keylistener event) and
   put in formsum, how to do it ??.
2. In formsum I also have "Save" button
   after click this button I want to
   save data from all form to xml, how
   to get values from all fields, from
   each form ??

Edit:

```
    panel.add(t.initComponents());  
    ArrayList machineList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i< machines.size(); i++)
    {   
        Form f = new Form();        
        machineList.add(f);
        panel.add(f.initComponents());
    }
    panel.add(new Formsum(machineList));
```

And in  Formsum

```
for(int i=0; i< machines.size(); i++)
{
    Form machine = (Form) machines.get(i);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, machine.getEcoef().getText());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the components of the forms, you need to either go through the children om `panel` or (better) save references to the forms you create in a list, and traverse this list when the user clicks save.